# Is there a list of existing businesses that have started to accept Bitcoin?

Tags: business

As opposed to new business that sprung up and accept Bitcoin from day 1.

I believe it will much shorter than the [Trade wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade), and perhaps more valuable in a certain way.

Comment: ... Or harmful, depending on how much work is done maintaining it. I'd say the complete list is longer than you'd think, and if only a few are added to the page it will create a bad impression. You may also want to tighten the criteria because there are a lot of small, insignificant services that added a Bitcoin donation option.

Comment: Maybe a better way to make the trade list more valuable is to prune any defunct entries, and sort entries by decreasing importance. A new service founded on Bitcoin and growing to be better/larger than previously existing alternatives should be as visible as them.

Comment: could you define "from day 1" ? for sure no businesses were accepting bitcoin when the initial annouce have been made by satoshi . . .

Comment: @neofutur - I mean that I'm not looking for business that from _their_ first day accepted Bitcoin (e.g. http://cheaperinbitcoins.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I created [this page on the Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Existing_business_that_have_started_accepting_Bitcoin), please add to it.

(BTW, the wiki is extremely slow for the last day or so)